# How can I have more than one theme/colour on the same file extension, but matched against filename?

Tags: sublimetext3

Example:

**Theme colour 1:**

- test/validation/validation.spec.js
- test/navbar/navbar.spec.js
- test/accordion/accordion.spec.js

**Theme colour 2:**

- src/validation/validation.js
- src/navbar/navbar.js
- src/accordion/accordion.js

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Conditional%20ColorSchemes

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks very much